# How to use DSM & Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, vocabulary

Does anyone know what I would set as the value for the "content" attribute if I'm utilizing the *Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders* (DSM)?

```html
  <span itemprop="code" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalCode">
    <meta itemprop="code" content="305.90"/>
    <meta itemprop="codingSystem" content="_______"/>
  </span>
```

Might the `codingSystem` content value be "DSM-IV", "DSM-4", "DSM4" or "DSM-4"?

Answer (score 0):

Schema.org doesn’t restrict how the value for the [`codingSystem` property](http://schema.org/codingSystem) should be specified (apart from the recommendation that the value should be *Text*).

You should use the name/abbreviation that is most widely known. Wikipedia [lists it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnostic_and_Statistical_Manual_of_Mental_Disorders#DSM-IV_.281994.29) as "DSM-IV", so unless you know better, go with this.

I don’t know anything about this domain, but I think [`codeValue`](http://schema.org/codeValue) (which expects Text) is more appropriate than [`code`](http://schema.org/code) (which expects another `MedicalCode` item):

```html
<span itemprop="code" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalCode">
  <meta itemprop="codeValue" content="305.90" />
  <meta itemprop="codingSystem" content="DSM-4" />
</span>
```